# Save responseObject JSON into NSCachedURLResponse for ios?

Tags: ios, json, swift, nscache

I am having trouble with saving JSON to `NSCachedURLResponse`.

This is my code:

```
 operation.responseSerializer = AFJSONResponseSerializer()
 operation.setCompletionBlockWithSuccess({ (operation, responseObject) -> Void in  
    var cachedResponse = NSCachedURLResponse(response: operation.response,
        data: operation.responseData)
    NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().storeCachedResponse(cachedResponse, forRequest: request)
 })
```

I know that this code has no actual error but it's causing a JSON format problem. 
By saving `operation.response` and `operation.responsedata` its causing the JSON to be formatted like `"feed":` instead of `feed =`.

I've printed the `responseObject` which is the JSON before saving it was like `feed =`. so my problem with saving the `responseObject` into `NSCachedURLResponse` with its original formatting.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Well, you are trying to print the raw data, and you are looking for string json I guess you should use `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(receivedData,options:NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments,nil);` to get the json object.